# Using LIKE when searching for "%"

Tags: mysql

I want to check whether a column starts with "%".
Normally if I were to search for another character I would do this like code below but this doesn't work when searching for "%".

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `column` LIKE 'anothercharacter%'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE column LIKE 'anothercharacter%[%]%'
```

OR

```
WHERE column LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```